# When requesting WebGL2, any browser gives me a WebGL1 context (emscripten)

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

I am trying to receive a WebGL 2.0 context.
I am using `-s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s MIN_WEBGL_VERSION=2` and have tried adding `-s FULL_ES3=1`. Compiling gives neither warnings nor errors. I use the GLES3/ headers.

Furthermore:

```
EmscriptenWebGLContextAttributes atrs;
emscripten_webgl_init_context_attributes(&atrs);
atrs.alpha = true;
atrs.depth = true;
atrs.stencil = false;
atrs.majorVersion = 2;
atrs.minorVersion = 0;

emctx = emscripten_webgl_create_context(id, &atrs);
emscripten_webgl_make_context_current(emctx);
std::cout << "GL_VERSION=" << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
```

The result in Chrome's console:

```
OpenGL ES 2.0 (WebGL 1.0 (OpenGL ES 2.0 Chromium))
```

And a very similar result in Firefox.

I've been searching for about a week already how to get this right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally I have tried everything, and found the solution. My problem was, that I had been compiling with a makefile, and that my .cpp turned to .o files with all the appropriate flags, but in the linker step, you also need to specify those flags, or WebGL2.0 won't be available.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit like [0], try adding `-lGL` to your link flags.

[0] https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/12118

Comment: It didn't make a difference. The -s STRICT -s MAX_WEBGL_VERSION=2 didn't, either. I am on Ubuntu with a default graphics driver (for an NVidia on notebook). Could it simply be a system configuration issue? But in JavaScript, I am getting "webgl2" with no problem whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran in to an issue like that. Could it be that you need to edit the `library_browser.js` in Emscripten to give you a 'webgl2' context rather than '2d'?

It writes `getContext('2d')` when compiling and has to be edited to `getContext('webgl2',yourSettings)` in `library_browser.js` before compiling.